# Vandermonde's identity induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction, alternative-proof

Is there is a proof of Vandermonde's identity by induction over $r$ ?

I have read the proof by induction, **but its over $n$ not $r$** ...

Vandermonde's identity:

> $${n \choose r} = \sum_{i=0}^{r}{ {{t}\choose{i}} { {n-t} \choose {r-i} } }$$

Comment: I don't understand at all why you'd try induction over $r$ rather than $m$. An induction argument over $m$ good for any $r \le m$ should suffice.

Comment: @Chris i know that induction over $m$ is better and easier, but i wanted to see it over $r$ for practicing ...

Comment: $n=m$ I suppose ?

Comment: @Evargalo I
 corrected it, thanks